# Group of order $p^2+p $ is not simple

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Can some one please give me a hint to prove that every group of order $p^2+p$ is not simple?

Comment: Not even for the smallest primes you get a fortiori a cyclic group...

Comment: Every group of order $p^2+p$ for some prime $p$ is not cyclic (For example for $p=2$, we have $S_3$). But you can try Sylow theorems to see that if the group is not simple, then there must be $p+1$ different Sylow $p$-subgroups which leads to a contradiction.

Comment: @Levent The first sentence is meant as "not every group of order $p^2+p$ is cyclic", I suppose. Not every group of order $p^2+p$ is not cyclic.

Comment: Yeah that's what I said?

Comment: No, you said "every group of order $p^2+p$ for some prime $p$ is not cyclic", which is wrong, because the cyclic group of that order is cyclic.

Comment: This question is more interesting than it looks, because it does not say anything about $p$ being prime (although everyone seems to be assuming it is). I don't know whether the statement is true for all positive integers $p$. There are no counterexamples with $p \le 10^6$.

Comment: @DerekHolt It's pretty safe to assume that the letters $p,q$ are implicitly referring to primes unless otherwise specified in cases like these, though you're right that it does make for an interesting question to remove it.

Comment: Yes $p$ is usually prime, although $q$ is less certain, and $r$ very likely not!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the proof in the duplicate question is partly buried in the comments, there is no harm in repeating it.

Assuming that $p$ is prime, if $G$ is simple, then $G$ has $p+1$ Sylow $p$-subgroups, which must intersect trivially, so we have a total of $p^2-1$ elements of order $p$, the indentity, and $p$ other elements.

Let $g$ be one of these other elements. Then $g$ cannot be centralized by an element of order $p$, since the Sylow $p$-subgroups are self-normalizing, so $|C_G(g)| \le p+1$. On the other hand, $g$ has at most $p$ conjugates, so it must have exactly $p$ conjugates, and $|C_G(g)|=p+1$.

But then $C_G(g)$ must consist of exactly of the identity and the elements not of order $p$, so it is a normal subgroup of $G$, contradicting simplicity.