# Do there exist simple groups of order $n(n+1)$ for some integer $n>1$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, simple-groups

In the [comments to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1784687/group-of-order-p2p-is-not-simple), it was remarked that the question of whether a finite group of order $p(p+1)$ is necessarily not simple becomes fairly interesting if we do not assume that $p$ is a prime— if it is a prime, that question's answer and the linked duplicate's answers (and comments) answers in the affirmative.

The following basic GAP code

```
for n in [2..10^5] do 
  iter:=SimpleGroupsIterator(n*(n+1),n*(n+1)); 
  for i in iter do 
    Print(n, "->", i, "\n"); 
    break; 
  od; 
od;
```

Shows that no simple groups of such order exist for $n\leq 10^5$ (so no examples with $|G|\leq 10^5(10^5+1)$).  The iterator function quickly starts hitting issues soon after this point, especially once the order meets or exceeds $|A_{15}|$, which occurs before $n=10^6$, limiting how far one can search with this method.  It takes a few minutes to check up through $n=10^5$.  The following variant finds no simple groups of suitable order before $A_{15}$:

```
iter := SimpleGroupsIterator(3,Factorial(15)/2-1);; 
for G in iter do 
  if (Tau(4*Order(G)+1) mod 2) = 1 then 
    Print(G, "  ", Order(G), "\n"); 
    break; 
  fi; 
od;
```

I would expect one should be able to hammer out a proof that all such groups are not simple (assuming this is a true statement) by using the classification of finite simple groups and doing a brute-force check on the sporadic and infinite family orders.  But is there a less brutal and more clever way, or does such a simple group actually exist?

EDIT: A few hours later, and the first bit of code finished checking up through $n=10^6$ and found no examples, as was claimed by Derek Holt in the aforementioned comments.

Comment: Going by the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_finite_simple_groups, clearly the Cyclic ones do not satisfy this. I checked the alternating groups from $A_n$ for $n \in \{5,...,99\}$ and found nothing, nor did I find anything in the sporadic simple groups. EDIT: perhaps I should mention that, rather than using GAP to go through all groups, I'm simply using the formulas given there to go through all possible orders.

Comment: @SteamyRoot Yes, that's what I meant that you should be able to brute force the answer via the classification theorem.  For the record, I would accept, or at least up vote and appreciate, a conclusive answer that used the classification.  Though I would prefer an answer that doesn't use one, if possible.

Comment: I agree that a proof not using the classification would be nicer, but currently I'm just trying to brute-force for some counterexamples. Anyway, any non-abelian finite simple group has even order, and a necessary requirement to be of the form $n(n+1)$ is that $4|G|+1$ is a perfect square. I'm not sure if that would be useful, but who knows...

Comment: @SteamyRoot  That's actually what I used in the second bit of code: the $\tau$ function is odd if and only if the input is a perfect square.  I haven't tried eliminating any families with it, though.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't really looked at that. Anyway, the list on http://www.madore.org/~david/math/simplegroups.html contains no orders such that $4|G|+1$ is a perfect square.

Comment: Right, I made a (badly coded and most likely very inefficient) Python script using the formulas from Wikipedia. It probably is more efficient than the GAP script, though. So far, I have found no counterexamples with $|G| < 10^{15}$ (which took about 20 seconds, assuming a large enough list of prime powers is already present). If anyone wants a try or wants to check for bugs/mistakes/stupidities, the code is at http://pastebin.com/EktW4zgQ .

Comment: Well, I upgraded the script quite a bit and managed to check all orders up to $10^{23}$, with no counterexamples found. The update code can be found at http://pastebin.com/HyKGVbWR. I probably won't bother looking any further, though.

Answer (score 5):

The alternating groups $A_m$ are ruled out for sufficiently large $m$ by the abc conjecture. If $n(n+1) = \frac{m!}{2}$, then by the abc conjecture we have (starting from the identity $n + 1 = (n+1)$) for any $\varepsilon > 0$ a constant $K_{\varepsilon}$ such that

$$n < K_{\varepsilon} \text{rad}(n(n+1))^{1 + \varepsilon}$$

for all $n$, but $\text{rad}(n(n+1)) = \text{rad} \left( \frac{m!}{2} \right)$ is the product of all the primes less than or equal to $m$. This is asymptotically about $e^m$, whereas $n$ is asymptotically about $\left( \frac{m}{e} \right)^{\frac{m}{2}}$ by Stirling's approximation.

Comment: Is there any way to decide how large is "sufficiently large" here?

Comment: Not without proving the abc conjecture...